# Orangehrm Implementing list filter to display duration in hours

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony, symfony-1.4, orangehrm

My question is how I can implement a cell filter in Orangehrm?

What I want to do is to display leave duration in leave lists in hours (8 hours per day) instead of days if the duration is less than one day (minimum casual leave is 30 minutes).

I wrote a cell filter class as below

```html
<?php

class workHourConverterFilter extends ohrmCellFilter {
    
    public function filter($value) {
        if ($value < 1.00 $$ $value != 0.50) {
   $value * 8;
   return $value;
  }
  return $value;
    }
}

?>
```

I want to register this filter and implement it in the leave list configuration factory file.

Comment: Is there a way to filter a value in the list ? Ex : In a given table I need to filter a user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **length_hours** field of "ohrm_leave" table for display duration in hours in leave list. I hope this may be useful to you.

Comment: You're right but the problem is that I want to show leaves extending for more than one day in days and leaves extending for less than one day in hours in the same table